# Expected value of an AR(1)

Tags: forecasting

Consider the AR(1) model
y_t=α+βy_(t-1)+e_t
Where the errors are white noise N(0, 1).
What is the expected value of y_t.

Comment: This seems to be a home work question or sort of with no minimal effort. It would be appreciable to mention what problems OP faced while approaching the problem.

Comment: would you please exlain what is the problem and why you can't answer this question? :-)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you know, i.e.

$E[y_t] = E[\alpha+\beta y_{t-1}+e_t]$

$E[e_t]$ is zero, so

$E[y_t] = \alpha+\beta E[y_{t-1}]$

If you know $y_{t-1}$ then $E[y_t] = \alpha+\beta y_{t-1}$

Comment: If it is the unconditional expectation which it seems to be, stationarity is standardly assumed under which Ey_t = Ey_t-1. Using this identity the equation is easy to solve for Ey_t

Answer (score 0):

if your process is stationary $E[y_{t}] = E[y_{t-1}] = \mu$, if we apply expectation at the both sides of AR(1) expression:

$$\overbrace{E[y_{t}]}^{\mu} = \alpha + \beta \underbrace{E[y_{t-1}]}_{\mu} + \overbrace{E[e_{t}]}^{0}$$

$$\mu = \alpha + \beta\mu \longleftrightarrow \mu = \frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}$$